# Firebase SignatureInvalidException when checking token

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get the following error when validating my google token, yet when i request this url https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?id_token={mytoken}
with the value of mytoken I get a valid request with data back.

This is the line that's causing the error:

here is the calling function:

```
$payload = $this->jwt->decode(
        $idToken,
        $rsa->getPublicKey(),
        array('RS256')
    );
```

This is from the library

```
if (!static::verify("$headb64.$bodyb64", $sig, $key, $header->alg)) {
    throw new SignatureInvalidException('Signature verification failed');
}
```

Why is the firebase library throwing an error?

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException
>
> Message: Signature verification failed
>
> Filename: /var/www/Forge/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php
>
> Line Number: 112

Comment: `composer update google/apiclient`

Comment: @edward - did this solve the issue for you? I'm facing the same thing and trying to figure it out.